# Android with Cordova : removing peripherals access from an application

Tags: android, cordova

By default, a cordova/android application can access to several peripherals as the read phone status, record audio, approximate location network and so and so on.
This access needs authorizations when I deploy on google apps.
My application doesn't need to access these peripherals, it only displays forms and reads/writes data with an API Rest.
My question :
how can I remove these access?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, you have to remove the plugins by :
cordova plugin remove